# How can one ensure that FileStream is disposed of after all WriteAsync() on the current file are complete?

Tags: c#, asynchronous, stream, async-await, filestream

I have the following event delegate that basically takes in an array of bytes, and appends it to a filestream.  Once it has written 1,000 times, which is tracked by a local variable `counter`, I want to close the current filestream and open a new one.

I read through the documentation of FileStream, and it suggested using `FileStream.WriteAsync()` for better performance.

```
public void WriteData(byte[] data)
{
   counter++;
   if (counter == 1000)
   {
         counter = 0;

         // Close the current filestream and open a new one.
          filestream.Dispose();
          filestream = new FileStream(this.outputPath, FileMode.Create,
            FileAccess.Write, FileShare.None, 4096, true);
   }

   filestream.WriteAsync(data, 0, data.Length);
}
```

However, in the function above, my hypothesis is that it might be the case that all the `WriteAsync()` calls have not completed before I call `filestream.Dispose()`.  Is there a way to ensure that I only `Dispose()` after all my `WriteAsync()` calls have been completed?  Note that this event delegate is being called 1,000 - 2,000 times per second in sequence, and WriteAsync is copying 240 KB per call to a SSD.

One solution that I can think of is instead of immediately disposing of each `Filestream` immediately, I can store it in an array of `Filestream` and then dispose of them once I am finished with the entire data writing process and no more events are firing.  Would that work?  Even then, how can I effectively "wait" until all the `WriteAsync()` calls have completed?

Comment: `await filestream.WriteAsync(...); filestream.Dispose;` ?

Comment: @Kritner The stream is not disposed after every write.

Comment: You shouldn't have a `void` asynchronous method like this.  You should always be exposing to the caller a means of determining when the asynchronous action has completed (in this case, by returning a `Task`).  Note that with your current code not only can you dispose of the stream while a write is in progress, but you can send in an additional write while an earlier write isn't finished yet, which will *also* cause problems.

Comment: So I guess the issue is that we are calling many instances of `WriteData()` within the timespan of each other.  I'm worried that even if we put `filestream.Dispose()` after the `await filestream.WriteAsync(...)`, it will dispose after the 1000th call, but the `WriteAsync(...)` from the 999th call might not have finished yet.

Comment: @Servy understood, thanks for the feedback.

Comment: @ArKi `WriteAsync()` is unlikely to be any faster than the sync equivalent, and it's actually likely to perform marginally worse, as asynchrony is not about raw performance in that sense.  It will however, allow whatever invoked your event handler to return back to whatever it was doing virtually as soon as the `WriteAsync()` method is called, rather than wait for it to complete as would happen with the sync version.

Comment: @ArKi A second consideration is that with the frequency of events you mention, with async - at least the way you have it there - there is no intrinsic guarantee that the writing to the file will be in the order of firing of the events.  It's possible that event N+1 will actually achieve write completion before event N, depending on how the task scheduler ends up executing the tasks.

Comment: @sellotape So let's say that any event will write `M` bytes.  Does that mean that event N+1 might write to bytes `1...M` and event N might write to bytes `M...2M`?  Behaviorally, when we are done writing everything to the file, I want the bytes written in the sequence that the events were fired.  The order of the write call completion doesn't matter to me, unless it would negatively impact performance.

Comment: @ArKi Yes I'm suggesting that's possible.  It depends on the implementation of `WriteAsync()`, but imagine it's something like "try to open file for write/append > fail because the previous event still has it open > sleep for 20ms (while allowing other threads to execute) > try again".  In that 20ms, event N+1's "try to open file" might succeed, and it will then write before event N manages to.  BTW this is purely hypothetical - I have no idea how `WriteAsync()` is actually implemented - but I think you need to consider it.

Comment: BTW I've slightly mixed up opening and writing to the file in that previous comment, but it would apply at the recycling points, which for you is a few times a second.  There are other things to consider too, like event N+1 might dispose the FileStream while event N is still busy with it...

Comment: @sellotape I guess I'm looking to solve two issues.  One, I want the bytes written in the order that the events were fired.  Two, I want it to be done off the main UI thread.  Is the best way to ensure these conditions to basically assign a dedicated thread to perform all these writes synchronously?  How do I ensure that a single thread handles all the delegate calls?  (I've not delved that much into threading thus far, so forgive the naive question.)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

While not an answer to the exact question, based on the follow-up in comments I'd suggest you do the following:

- Create a `ConcurrentQueue` in whatever is firing the events
- On each event, add to that queue
- Create a separate thread that services the queue, dequeuing events and writing them to disk.  You can then control exactly how frequently you want to open, write, rename, etc., and you have no thread concurrency issues on the file activity to deal with.
- Depending on your requirement, in your writer thread you could just poll the queue every second or so, or you could have a more sophisticated approach using `WaitHandle`s to signal when data is ready for writing, when the queue is empty, when it's got N items in it, etc.  As you're accumulating data so frequently, perhaps polling is fine as you'll almost always find data to write.
- You obviously need to handle closing the app cleanly - e.g. stop writing from events, single to the writing thread to stop, have it flush the last items to disk, wait for it to stop.

It's more work, but you get:

- guaranteed order
- almost no time spent in the event handler
- no concurrency issues (except for managing setup and tear down)
- delays in writing - e.g. due to OS, disk, network - do not block the main app
- a risk of losing event data if you lose power or the app aborts (you will have this with any solution that doesn't wait for the data to be written after each event)

There are probably out-the-box solutions out there for this (using a buffered log4net Appender comes to mind); this is if you want to roll your own.

You could do this with 'standard' threading (i.e. `Thread`), or you could just create your writing thread as a `Task`.